# python facebook wall post (#200)

Tags: python, facebook

I'm use facebook-sdk-0.4.0
I trying run from my server

```
access_token = get_app_access_token(settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, settings.FACEBOOK_API_SECRET)
graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
response = graph.put_wall_post(profile_id='274460312618957', message=message, attachment={'link':link, })
```

But have error

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this
>   action

I have admin-rules of this page (274460312618957)
I have admin-rules of this APP settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID

Way error (#200) ??

Comment: How can "Page Access Token" for FB-app on my site  with out User actions?


I just need to share on the wall of the Facebook page in reference to an entry in my blog when I publish

Answer (score 1):

You need `publish_stream` permission for your app in order to create posts as detailed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post). As to why you get a response code `200`, they are detailed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#receiving-errorcodes)

Comment: how can I get it(publish_stream permission ) with facebook-sdk from server side ? with out user actions ...
No example or description :(
sorry for my English I'm from Ukraine.